# How to display 20+ Columns using react-bootstrap-table-next

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to use react-bootstrap-table-next to render a table with over 20 columns. Right now my data is rendering, but with so many columns the text is compressed. Is there a horizontal scroll option or column header pagination for such a table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table that is too wide, maybe you could try the following:

Add a container element,with a *custom css class* that sets: `overflow-x:auto`, around the table. This should display a horizontal scroll bar when necessary. For example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-horiz-scroll" >
  <table>
    <tr><!-- row headers--></tr>
    <tr><!-- row 1 data--></tr>
    <tr><!-- row 2 data--></tr>
    <tr><!-- ... --></tr>
    <tr><!-- row n data--></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .table-horiz-scroll {
    overflow-x:auto;
 }
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if I want to add Horizontal Scrollbar only to the last two columns. Last two columns should be wrapped in a scrollable container. How can we implement this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64114303/how-to-add-horizontal-scrollbar-in-a-react-bootstrap-table

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, add 'responsive' to table.

import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'

```
 <Table responsive>
```

[Official docs for detailed answer](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/table/)